# R - Multiple search and replace based on partial match within a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list of publisher that looks like this :

```
+--------------+
|  Site Name   |
+--------------+
| Radium One   |
| Euronews     |
| EUROSPORT    |
| WIRED        |
| RadiumOne    |
| Eurosport FR |
| Wired US     |
| Eurosport    |
| EuroNews     |
| Wired        |
+--------------+
```

I'd like to create the following result:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|  Site Name   | Publisher Name |
+--------------+----------------+
| Radium One   | RadiumOne      |
| Euronews     | Euronews       |
| EUROSPORT    | Eurosport      |
| WIRED        | Wired          |
| RadiumOne    | RadiumOne      |
| Eurosport FR | Eurosport      |
| Wired US     | Wired          |
| Eurosport    | Eurosport      |
| EuroNews     | Euronews       |
| Wired        | Wired          |
+--------------+----------------+
```

I would like to understand how I can replicate this code I use in Power Query :

search first 4 characters

if Text.Start([Site Name],4) = "WIRE" then "Wired" else

search last 3 characters

if Text.End([Site Name],3) = "One" then "RadiumOne" else

If no match is found, then add "Rest"

It does not have to be case sensitive.

Comment: Looks like there is not any consistent pattern i.e. `RadiumOne` remains as `RadiumOne` while `EuroNews` changes to `Euronews`

Comment: That's true, but this is just a partial case. Let's take the case where I have `Cloud_DCUInteractive_FR_970x250_RM_03.zip` and want to find and replace it with only `DCU`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `properCase` from `ifultools` package  and `gsub`, we replace everything after first word with "" i.e delete it and treat the exceptional case of Radium separtely. If you have many exceptions like Radium case, please update your post with those so that we can find a neater solution to this hack :)

```
library("ifultools")

siteName=c("Radium One","Euronews","EUROSPORT","WIRED","RadiumOne","Eurosport FR","Wired US","Eurosport","EuroNews","Wired")

publisherName = gsub("^Radium$","Radiumone",gsub("\\s+.*","",properCase(siteName)))

 # [1] "Radiumone" "Euronews"  "Eurosport" "Wired"     "Radiumone" "Eurosport" "Wired"    
 # [8] "Eurosport" "Euronews"  "Wired"
```

Comment: That works in terms of case and first word, but what if I wanted to have the equivalent of a series of nested `gsub` based on partial match (`.*` style)? For example to search and replace `CloudDCU_MEA_BAN_V1` with `DCU` , `Cld_PIHEN_TD_01` for `PIH` and `Clod_TemeE_MEA_STD_01` for `Teme.

Comment: Is there any semblance of pattern in your inputs, as @akrun rightly mentioned earlier, its not possible to generalize a regular expression if there is no pattern to exploit

Comment: The `ifultools` package is no longer in the regular CRAN contributed listing if you don’t already have it you will need to install from source.